# How to uninstall standalone QGIS & reinstall in OSgeo4w on Win7?

Tags: qgis, installation, osgeo

I need to apply a patch to QGis but installed as standalone instead of OSGeo4w: foolish.

I'd like to uninstall then reinstall via OSGeo4w so as to have linux-like  updating support, but before I do so, can anyone advise me whether my maps & WMS info will be saved, or if there's anything one specifically needs to do to avoid extra headaches/work during this process?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps and WMS Info are stored in your user profile, or the registry.

I have QGIS Lisboa standalone and OSGEO4W Master installed in parallel, and both can open the same projects (unless some new or deprecated plugins are installed).

I would not encourage you to relay only on Master, as it gets broken from time to time.

Comment: Interesting, thanks Andre. So I could just install OSGeo4W now and QGis through that, and use the standalone install if/when the OSgeo4w install breaks?

Comment: Hmm... what if I already have OSGeo4W installed and it doesn't work... can I uninstall & reinstall?

Comment: I use standalone for daily work, and master just for testing new things. If OSGEO4W gets messed up, just delete or rename the root folder, and make a fresh install (or do it on another drive). Older versions of OSGeo4w-setup.exe had a bug, so better use a fresh copy of that too.

Comment: Note that you can install both the stable release and current master from OSGeo4W in parallel without need of any stand-alone installers.

Comment: interesting. Ok, it feels like a seemingly-buggy OSgeo4W might as well be fully uninstalled w/ qgis (backing everything up) then reinstalling OSgeo4W w/ qgis current master, then installing qgis stable if/when the current master breaks. For reference, I can patch the stable version from the repository right?

Comment: @dez93_2000 It's not a good idea to use master for critical work-related projects. You might introduce dependencies which make it impossible to open the projects in 1.8 in case master breaks. If you need some processing tools which are only in master, do the processing there and take the results back into a 1.8 project.

Comment: ah....hmm. Thanks for this @Underdark, very good to know beforehand! Perhaps you guys can suggest my best course of action then - I simply want to patch with this [link](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/repository/revisions/bb623a8c94e49ed478f736a58df49732edd338b4) so I can use qgis with a bad internet connection. What would you suggest?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In that case, I suggest: Get master, if it works for you, don't update it anymore. That way you can't break it.

Comment: Good thinking! Thanks a lot everyone. I'd upvote answers but don't have enough rep - sorry!

Comment: heh, good point, i didn't officially say thanks to you for starting this off!!